# Issue in drilldown of highcharts multiseries chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to configure multi series chart in Highchart with drill down features.

I am able to drilldown but it is not happening properly. Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/V9cfZ/1/)

```
I am using the drilldown api
```

What I am doing wrong here?.

**EDIT** : My Problem

I have 4 countries with their export and import data (Made up data). On clicking on either export or import column of a particular country, say Export of USA, I want to drill down to export of USA which contains a line chart of 2 data points. I am able to drill down but, the other series is not getting hidden/removed. How to solve this?

Comment: Could you please explain your problem? As I am unable to understand from fiddle demo

Comment: I just added the explanation for more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now it's not supported in Highcharts to drilldown for more series.

Bug reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2604).

Comment: Bug has since been resolved, I believe OP's solution should now work, here's another example: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/WCCDZ/